# Authentication system for ASP.NET web applications?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have some question:

How to make a role based web application? Such as in forum sites, there is many user types, admin, moderator etc... is the roles of these user types stored in database or web.config? And when a user login to our site, how to control this users roles? In short I want to learn about authorization and authentication.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mavera:

Basicly, its the concept of having your own users table in your own database, where you can manage permissions and store login information (Properly hashed of course). In the case of a multi-level permission scheme, I usually use two or more tables, for example:

```
TblUsers:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| UserID (PK) | UserName | HashedPassword | PermissionLevel (FK)|
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1       | BobTables| adfafs2312     |         2           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

TblPermissions
-------------------------------------
|  PermissionID (PK) | Description   |
--------------------------------------
|         1          |     User      |
|         2          |   SuperUser   |
|         3          |     Admin     |
--------------------------------------
```

You can add 3rd table that contains a One-To-Many relationship between TblPermissions that exposes the actual abilities the user may be allowed to do.

Querying a user would be as simple as:

```
SELECT TblUser.Username, TblPermissions.Description 
    FROM TblUsers, TblPermissions 
    WHERE TblUser.UserID = @UserID 
    AND TblUser.PermissionLevel = TblPermission.PermissionID;
```

Create a custom class to encapsulate that information, and store it in ASP.NET session when they are logged in.

Answer (score 8):

Check this articles and videos:

- [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)
- [Managing Authorization Using Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0.aspx)
- [Creating the Application Services Database for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)
- [Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)
- [Membership and Role Providers in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/427.aspx) (Tutorial)
- [ASP .NET Security Videos](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/security-videos/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the built in Authorization schemes work great for simple situations where you only need to basically authenticate who can enter and who can leave, but fall short for custom situations, such as having special administrator accounts etc.

In those situations, I've created my own authentication scheme.